# Creating a query to aggregate 3 Month, 6 Month totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregation

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.  I'm trying to create a query that aggregates totals by 3M, 6M, 9M, 12M totals.  Here is some sample data:

```
create table invoice (store int, invoice_date datetime, customer int, is_repeat varchar(1));

insert into invoice (store, invoice_date, customer, is_repeat)
values (1, '2015-10-05', 1, 'N'),
(1, '2016-03-04', 1, 'Y'),
(1, '2016-02-07', 1, 'Y'),
(1, '2015-08-03', 2, 'Y'),
(2, '2015-12-01', 3, 'Y'),
(2, '2016-02-16', 4, 'Y'),
(2, '2015-06-11', 3, 'Y'),
(2, '2015-09-18', 4, 'Y');
```

The query needs to give a 3M, 6M, etc count of 'Y' values and aggregate it by store, month, and year.  For example, there should be a record for Store 1 for March 2016 that totals the number of 'Y' values between 12/1/2015 and 02/29/2016 and puts that value in the 3M column.  Then also sum the values between 9/1/2015 and 02/29/2016 and put those values in the 6M column.

Here's an example of the what the query results should be for the above data:

```
STORE     MONTH     YEAR     3M_REPEATS     6M_REPEATS
-----     -----     ----     ----------     ----------
  1         2       2016         0              2
  1         3       2016         1              2
  2         2       2016         1              3
  2         3       2016         2              3
```

I'm trying to find an elegant solution but I'm not sure if I should use a CTE, or PIVOT, or OVER(PARTITION BY), or just standard GROUP BY clauses.

**EDIT TO ADD:** I ultimately just need the last 12 months in this table, so there would only be 12 records in this table.  For example, if current month/year is 3/2016, it would have 2/2015 - 3/2016 and the totals for each month.

Comment: If there is no record at all that falls during a month (e.g. November 2015 in your samples), does that still need to be shown as a row in the results?

Comment: @Ross Presser Yes, for a given store, month, and year, if there are no records where is_repeat = 'Y' in the past 3 months/6 months, I would still want to see a record for that store/month/year but with 0's for the 3M and 6M totals.  In my sample data for Store 2, the November 2015 result row would have 3M_REPEATS = 1 and 6M_REPEATS = 2, due to the 2015-09-18 and 2015-06-11 invoice_date values.  I hope this answers your question and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

sum records that fall in each quarter by using a case statement to get the quarter for each record then use a group by

```
select 
store,
datepart(m, invoice_date) as mth,
datepart(yyyy, invoice_date) as yr,
Sum(case when datename(qq,invoice_date)=1 then 1 else 0 end) as QTR1, 
Sum(case when datename(qq,invoice_date)=2 6 then 1 else 0 end) as QTR2
FROM test 
WHERE is_repeat='Y'
GROUP BY store, datepart(m, t.invoice_date), datepart(yyyy, t.invoice_date)
ORDER BY store, mth, yr
```

Answer (score 0):

I would SUM CASE expressions for the aggregations and GROUP BY Store, Month, Year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses analytic functions:

```
with agg as (
    select
        store,
        min(invoice_date) as invoice_month,
        count(case when is_repeat = 'Y' then 1 end) as y_count 
    from invoice
    where 
            invoice_date >= dateadd(month, -14, current_timestamp)
        and datediff(month, invoice_date, current_timestamp) between 1 and 12 
    group by
        store,
        datediff(month, invoice_date, current_timestamp)
)
select
    store,
    datepart(month, a1.invoice_month) as "month",
    datepart(year, a1.invoice_month) as "year",
    sum(y_count) over (
        partition by store
        order by invoice_month
        rows between 2 preceding and current row
    ) as 3m_repeats,
    sum(y_count) over (
        partition by store
        order by invoice_month
        rows between 5 preceding and current row
    ) as 6m_repeats
from agg
```

But since you can't use `rows between` on 2008 I think this works as a substitute:

```
with agg as (
    select
        store,
        min(invoice_date) as invoice_month,
        count(case when is_repeat = 'Y' then 1 end) as y_count 
    from invoice
    where 
            invoice_date >= dateadd(month, -14, current_timestamp)
        and datediff(month, invoice_date, current_timestamp) between 1 and 12 
    group by
        store,
        datediff(month, invoice_date, current_timestamp)
)
select
    store,
    datepart(month, a1.invoice_month) as "month",
    datepart(year, a1.invoice_month) as "year",
    sum(case
        when datediff(month, a1.invoice_date, a2.invoice_date)
            between -2 and 0
        then y_count end
    ) as 3m_repeats,
    sum(case
        when datediff(month, a1.invoice_date, a2.invoice_date)
            between -5 and 0 then y_count end
    ) as 6m_repeats,
from agg a1 inner join agg a2
    on      a2.store = a1.store
        and datediff(month, a1.invoice_date, a2.invoice_date) between -5 and 0
group by a1.store, a1.invoice_month
```

I'm assuming you have data for all the months so I didn't bother with that complication.